# Error: Unknown field metrics.conversions - Google Ads Scripts Account Summary Report - Adding new columns

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I want to add new columns to the Account Summary Report:  https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/account-summary

But I'm getting an error.

```
'report_fields': [
{'columnName': 'metrics.cost_micros', 'displayName': 'Cost'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.average_cpc', 'displayName': 'Avg. CPC'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.ctr', 'displayName': 'CTR'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.search_impression_share', 'displayName': 'Search Impr. share'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.impressions', 'displayName': 'Impressions'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.clicks', 'displayName': 'Clicks'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.conversions', 'displayName': 'Conversions'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.conversions_value', 'displayName': 'Revenue'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.cost_per_conversion', 'displayName': 'CPA'},
{'columnName': 'metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate', 'displayName': 'CVR'}
```

--- Error---

```
Error: Unknown field metrics.conversions
    at format (Code:174:13)
    at Code:97:33
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at main (Code:96:55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ads Script code you linked to contains a function which correctly formats the different metrics being downloaded:

```js
function format(column, value) {
  switch (column) {
    case 'metrics.clicks':
    case 'metrics.impressions':
      return value;
    case 'metrics.ctr':
      return formatPercentage(value);
    case 'metrics.average_cpc':
    case 'metrics.cost_micros':
      return formatMicros(value);
    case 'metrics.search_impression_share':
      return formatImpressionShare(value);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown field ${column}`);
  }
}
```

You'll notice that every metric is individually listed. If you add `metrics.conversions` to the set of fields being downloaded, you'll need to adjust the `format` function as well—otherwise you'll encounter the *"Error: Unknown field metrics.conversions"* exception which is thrown in the `default` case.

As `metrics.conversions` is a regular number, you can just add a case for it at the top:

```js
function format(column, value) {
  switch (column) {
    case 'metrics.clicks':
    case 'metrics.impressions':
    case 'metrics.conversions':
      return value;
    case 'metrics.ctr':
      return formatPercentage(value);
    case 'metrics.average_cpc':
    case 'metrics.cost_micros':
      return formatMicros(value);
    case 'metrics.search_impression_share':
      return formatImpressionShare(value);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown field ${column}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks @dorian, it works, the script runs fine, but it logs a TypeError.

TypeError: newValue.indexOf is not a function
    at formatChangeString (Code:366:33)
    at emailRow (Code:314:11)
    at Code:285:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at sendEmail (Code:284:17)
    at main (Code:106:7)

Do you know what this could be?

Comment: Please create a new question for this problem. This will make it easier to see the full stack trace, for example.

Comment: It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73627493/account-summary-report-google-ads-script-not-sending-emails-after-i-added-new-me // Hope you can help :)