# Account Summary Report Google Ads Script not sending emails after I added new metrics

Tags: google-api, google-ads-script

I added conversion and revenue columns to the script which [can be found here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/account-summary#:%7E:text=Account%20Summary%20Report%20is%20an,formatted%20reports%20directly%20to%20clients.).

This is the error I'm getting in the logs (the spreadsheet is updating fine with no issues):

```
TypeError: newValue.indexOf is not a function
    at formatChangeString (Code:366:33)
    at emailRow (Code:314:11)
    at Code:285:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at sendEmail (Code:284:17)
    at main (Code:106:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatChangeString(newValue,oldValue)` expects `newValue` to be a string (so that `newValue.indexOf('%')` can be called.

It seems that one of the metrics you added is returned by the `AdsApp.report` call as a different type (most likely `Number`).

If you want a quick workaround, just change the line

```js
const isPercentage = newValue.indexOf('%') >= 0;
```

to

```js
const isPercentage = String(newValue).indexOf('%') >= 0;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you @dorian, it works now, just need to figure out how to format the values now so they show as either currency or percentage in the email. Spreadsheet is fine, just the email everything gets formatted as a number. Thanks for your help again :)